# How to get loaded and total for each file separately?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, upload

I'm just starting my adventure with javascript. I wanted to upload using ajax with a progress bar for each file separately. For one file, it works great for one file but for more files the progress looks exactly the same. How can I find the loaded and total for each file separately?

```
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("plik").files;
        // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    //formdata.append("plik", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    x;
    for(x = 0; x < file.length; x = x + 1) {
        formdata.append('plik[]', file[x]);

    }

    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "gc.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    var file = _("plik").files;
    var Pr = document.getElementById('uploadProgressStatus');
    Pr.style.display= "block";
    //console.log(file.[].name);
    var text = "";
    for(x = 0; x < file.length; x = x + 1) {

    text+=   '<div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; display: none;" ><span style="float: left;"><img src="/assets/images/upload.gif"></span><div>'+file[x].name+'</div><div id="ProgressBarBg'+x+'" style="width:300px; height: 2px; background: #DCDADA;"><div id="progressBar'+x+'" style="position: relative; top:0px; background: #5D9BF7; width:0%; height: 2px; color: #0FF; text-align:center;"></div></div></div>';

    }
_("uploadProgressStatus").innerHTML = text;
    for(x = 0; x < file.length; x = x + 1) {

        var ProgressBarBg = document.getElementById('ProgressBarBg'+x);
    ProgressBarBg.style.display= "block";
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;

var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar'+x);
progressBar.style.width = percent + "%";
if(percent === 100) {
    completeFile()
}
    }
}
}
function completeFile(filenumber) {

}
function completeHandler(event){
/*  var file = _("plik").files;
    for(x = 0; x < file.length; x = x + 1) {
$("#status").html("moze być");
  } */
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, in your for loops, instead of using `(x = 0; x < file.length; x = x + 1)`, you can just replace `x = x + 1` with `x += 1`, so `(x = 0; x < file.length; x += 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "progress" event is bound to only one ajax.upload object. If you want to track the upload progress for each file, you need to create an ajax object for each file upload. I rewrite the uploadFile() function. I create a new formData object and an ajax object for each file and bind "progress" event to each ajax.upload. Thus progressHandler() will be called whenever a file in _("plik").files is uploaded.

```
function uploadFile(){
    for(var x = 0; x < file.length; x++) {
        var file = _("plik").files,
            formdata = new FormData(),
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formdata.append('plik', file[x]);
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "gc.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
}
```

Try to rewrite progressHandler() function like below. Every time you upload a file, you should be able to see a changing percentage which represents the upload progress of that particular file.

```
function progressHandler(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentage = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
        _("uploadProgressStatus").innerHTML = percentage.toString() + "%"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but I do not know how to assign a specific upload status to the corresponding file. You can see the effect in the link below.http://test.digitaldrive.pl/fup2.php

Comment: I have modified my answer. You may try to rewrite your progressHandler() function like mine.